# USA - Why can't I write off my IRA contribution for 2017?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, ira, writeoffs

**Backstory**

Last year I made 60k from earned income and 25k from moving an investment - I was forced to realize the gain even though I reinvested into a managed portfolio. All in all I'm taxed at 85k.

**Problem**

I gave all this info to my CPA hoping to write off as much as possible including a ~10k contribution to my IRA (5k roth, 5k simple). However my CPA told me that I can't write off the IRA contribution because the money I would be writing off came from an investment.

**Question**

Does this make any sense? Is there any way around this?

Comment: I don't know anything about a simple IRA, but with a Roth IRA, the whole point is that the money you put in is taxed. The benefit of a Roth IRA is that the money isn't taxed _when you pull it out for retirement_.

Comment: Did you have any _earned_ income, or just these capital gains?

Comment: Your total IRA + Roth contribution is limited to 5.5k (6.5k if you are over 50). So if you put 5k+5k in there, there is a problem to begin with.

Comment: @DStanley 60k in regular income

Comment: @Aganju That sounds right. If so then I want to write off 5.5k (not 10) - still this problem stands in my way or so my CPA has told me.

Comment: Are you a W2 employee, or self-employed?

Comment: Do you mean simple as in uncomplicated, or the specific employer scheme SIMPLE? The answers interpret differently. If you mean plain-old personal trad IRA, that should indeed be deductible if not exceeding 5.5k/6.5k _or_ your compensation for all IRAs together and actually made by the unextended filing deadling of April 17.

Answer (score 2):

- Your Roth IRA contribution does not generate an immediate deduction (the earnings are tax favored instead).
- Your Simple IRA contribution was likey taken out as pre-tax dollars, thus you get no additional deduction.  Only an "eligible employer" with less than 100 may establish a SIMPLE IRA.
- Your investment income is not "earned", so could not be used to fund for example a self-employed SEP IRA.
- You did not contribute to a traditional IRA.  That would have resulted in a deduction.

The "source" of the money does not matter.

See https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/simple-ira-plan-faqs-contributions for the IRS FAQ on the handling of a SIMPLE.

Comment: "_with less than 100_" Might be a silly question, but 100 _what_?

Answer (score 0):

If you had ordinary income > 5k, then for the 5k you're contributing to the simple IRA, you should be able to claim that the contribution came from that income. For the Roth IRA, you contribute after-tax money, so you can't write off the money regardless of where it comes from.

Comment: Simple IRA has a $12,500 limit. Nothing like a good CPA.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I'm not sure what the point of that comment is.

Comment: A good CPA would know this, and not mislead OP.

Comment: It's not clear if OP means 'simple' as the ordinary English word for uncomplicated and here presumably traditional IRA, or SIMPLE which is an acronym for Savings Incentive Match Plan for Employees of Small Employers, a specific employer-sponsored type of IRA (as linked in the other answer) with a higher limit as @Joe says but must come from payroll and employer directly.

Comment: Well that certainly changes things. And unfortunate the OP hasn’t returned to clarify